# Regular Expression: exclude "/" (slash) from a replace

Tags: regex

I'm using F3 Framework.
It has a slug functions,as follow:

```
slug

Method to return a URL- and filesystem-friendly string.

string slug ( string $text )

The purpose of this function is to convert foreign characters to their approximate English keyboard character equivalents. Therefor it uses ISO-9 transliteration with a lookup table array that can be extended with the DIACRITICS var. Furthermore, it is designed to remove all non-alphanumeric characters and convert them to dashes.

echo Web::instance()->slug('ĤÈĹĹŌ'); // displays 'hello'
echo Web::instance()->slug('Ein schöner Artikel über Max & John!'); // displays 'ein-schoener-artikel-ueber-max-john'
```

The function itself is:

```
function slug($text) {
        return trim(strtolower(preg_replace('/([^\pL\pN])+/u','-',
            trim(strtr(str_replace('\'','',$text),
            array(
                'Ǎ'=>'A','А'=>'A','Ā'=>'A','Ă'=>'A','Ą'=>'A','Å'=>'A',
                'Ǻ'=>'A','Ä'=>'Ae','Á'=>'A','À'=>'A','Ã'=>'A','Â'=>'A',
                'Æ'=>'AE','Ǽ'=>'AE','Б'=>'B','Ç'=>'C','Ć'=>'C','Ĉ'=>'C',
                'Č'=>'C','Ċ'=>'C','Ц'=>'C','Ч'=>'Ch','Ð'=>'Dj','Đ'=>'Dj',
                'Ď'=>'Dj','Д'=>'Dj','É'=>'E','Ę'=>'E','Ё'=>'E','Ė'=>'E',
                'Ê'=>'E','Ě'=>'E','Ē'=>'E','È'=>'E','Е'=>'E','Э'=>'E',
                'Ë'=>'E','Ĕ'=>'E','Ф'=>'F','Г'=>'G','Ģ'=>'G','Ġ'=>'G',
                'Ĝ'=>'G','Ğ'=>'G','Х'=>'H','Ĥ'=>'H','Ħ'=>'H','Ï'=>'I',
                'Ĭ'=>'I','İ'=>'I','Į'=>'I','Ī'=>'I','Í'=>'I','Ì'=>'I',
                'И'=>'I','Ǐ'=>'I','Ĩ'=>'I','Î'=>'I','Ĳ'=>'IJ','Ĵ'=>'J',
                'Й'=>'J','Я'=>'Ja','Ю'=>'Ju','К'=>'K','Ķ'=>'K','Ĺ'=>'L',
                'Л'=>'L','Ł'=>'L','Ŀ'=>'L','Ļ'=>'L','Ľ'=>'L','М'=>'M',
                'Н'=>'N','Ń'=>'N','Ñ'=>'N','Ņ'=>'N','Ň'=>'N','Ō'=>'O',
                'О'=>'O','Ǿ'=>'O','Ǒ'=>'O','Ơ'=>'O','Ŏ'=>'O','Ő'=>'O',
                'Ø'=>'O','Ö'=>'Oe','Õ'=>'O','Ó'=>'O','Ò'=>'O','Ô'=>'O',
                'Œ'=>'OE','П'=>'P','Ŗ'=>'R','Р'=>'R','Ř'=>'R','Ŕ'=>'R',
                'Ŝ'=>'S','Ş'=>'S','Š'=>'S','Ș'=>'S','Ś'=>'S','С'=>'S',
                'Ш'=>'Sh','Щ'=>'Shch','Ť'=>'T','Ŧ'=>'T','Ţ'=>'T','Ț'=>'T',
                'Т'=>'T','Ů'=>'U','Ű'=>'U','Ŭ'=>'U','Ũ'=>'U','Ų'=>'U',
                'Ū'=>'U','Ǜ'=>'U','Ǚ'=>'U','Ù'=>'U','Ú'=>'U','Ü'=>'Ue',
                'Ǘ'=>'U','Ǖ'=>'U','У'=>'U','Ư'=>'U','Ǔ'=>'U','Û'=>'U',
                'В'=>'V','Ŵ'=>'W','Ы'=>'Y','Ŷ'=>'Y','Ý'=>'Y','Ÿ'=>'Y',
                'Ź'=>'Z','З'=>'Z','Ż'=>'Z','Ž'=>'Z','Ж'=>'Zh','á'=>'a',
                'ă'=>'a','â'=>'a','à'=>'a','ā'=>'a','ǻ'=>'a','å'=>'a',
                'ä'=>'ae','ą'=>'a','ǎ'=>'a','ã'=>'a','а'=>'a','ª'=>'a',
                'æ'=>'ae','ǽ'=>'ae','б'=>'b','č'=>'c','ç'=>'c','ц'=>'c',
                'ċ'=>'c','ĉ'=>'c','ć'=>'c','ч'=>'ch','ð'=>'dj','ď'=>'dj',
                'д'=>'dj','đ'=>'dj','э'=>'e','é'=>'e','ё'=>'e','ë'=>'e',
                'ê'=>'e','е'=>'e','ĕ'=>'e','è'=>'e','ę'=>'e','ě'=>'e',
                'ė'=>'e','ē'=>'e','ƒ'=>'f','ф'=>'f','ġ'=>'g','ĝ'=>'g',
                'ğ'=>'g','г'=>'g','ģ'=>'g','х'=>'h','ĥ'=>'h','ħ'=>'h',
                'ǐ'=>'i','ĭ'=>'i','и'=>'i','ī'=>'i','ĩ'=>'i','į'=>'i',
                'ı'=>'i','ì'=>'i','î'=>'i','í'=>'i','ï'=>'i','ĳ'=>'ij',
                'ĵ'=>'j','й'=>'j','я'=>'ja','ю'=>'ju','ķ'=>'k','к'=>'k',
                'ľ'=>'l','ł'=>'l','ŀ'=>'l','ĺ'=>'l','ļ'=>'l','л'=>'l',
                'м'=>'m','ņ'=>'n','ñ'=>'n','ń'=>'n','н'=>'n','ň'=>'n',
                'ŉ'=>'n','ó'=>'o','ò'=>'o','ǒ'=>'o','ő'=>'o','о'=>'o',
                'ō'=>'o','º'=>'o','ơ'=>'o','ŏ'=>'o','ô'=>'o','ö'=>'oe',
                'õ'=>'o','ø'=>'o','ǿ'=>'o','œ'=>'oe','п'=>'p','р'=>'r',
                'ř'=>'r','ŕ'=>'r','ŗ'=>'r','ſ'=>'s','ŝ'=>'s','ș'=>'s',
                'š'=>'s','ś'=>'s','с'=>'s','ş'=>'s','ш'=>'sh','щ'=>'shch',
                'ß'=>'ss','ţ'=>'t','т'=>'t','ŧ'=>'t','ť'=>'t','ț'=>'t',
                'у'=>'u','ǘ'=>'u','ŭ'=>'u','û'=>'u','ú'=>'u','ų'=>'u',
                'ù'=>'u','ű'=>'u','ů'=>'u','ư'=>'u','ū'=>'u','ǚ'=>'u',
                'ǜ'=>'u','ǔ'=>'u','ǖ'=>'u','ũ'=>'u','ü'=>'ue','в'=>'v',
                'ŵ'=>'w','ы'=>'y','ÿ'=>'y','ý'=>'y','ŷ'=>'y','ź'=>'z',
                'ž'=>'z','з'=>'z','ż'=>'z','ж'=>'zh','ь'=>'','ъ'=>''
            )+Base::instance()->get('DIACRITICS'))))),'-');
    }
```

As a completely inexpert with regex, I need to edit that `/([^\pL\pN])+/u` to EXCLUDE a "/" (slash) char from the conversion.

I don't know how edit it.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you can just add `\/` to the negated character class - `/[^\pL\pN\/]+/u`

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea, at all. It might break existing functionality or introduce security risks.